# I am trying to get dynamic value of a response variable in an api using jmeter json extractor and using reponse assertion of substring to assert it

Tags: json, jmeter

However, I'm unable to get the desired response in assertion. I have used json extractor and given
Name of created variable as : contenttype

Json path expression: $..contenttype

Default values: contenttype

And in the response assertion with pattern as substring I have given
"contenttype":${contenttype}

But in results I am getting assertion fail message like test expected to contain /"contenttype:":xyz/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot help without seeing:

1. The response (at least partial)
2. Your `contenttype` variable value (can be visualized using [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script))
3. The placement of the Response Assertion (I'm talking about [Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules))

So far I can only tell that:

1. The correct syntax for [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) is `${your-variable-name-here}` so you might want to change your expression to `"contenttype":${contenttype}`
2. If the value of the `contenttype` variable is supposed to be a [String](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_datatypes.asp) - in JSON it needs to be surrounded with quotation marks

   `"contenttype":"${contenttype}"`
3. If there are spaces around `:` like `"contenttype" : "VOD"` your response assertion will fail